# how to call stored procedure using DBCONTEXT in .net 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, dbcontext

**I have a stored procedure like below**

```
create procedure student.encrypt 
@text varchar(100)
@format varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
select student.EncrptString(@plainText,@Format)
END
Go
```

> How can I call this stored procedure using DBContext in .net 6?
> I have tried below code but getting no result
>
> > SP works fine SQL studio. EncrptString is user define function and dbo is the data base. SP returns string with no column name.

```
var y = _DBContext.EncryptString.FromSQLInterpolated($"exec student.encrypt {0},{1}",plaintext,format).SelectFirstorDefault();
```

> Where EncryptString is model class (I have created manually and not via code) created as below

```
EncryptString.cs
public string format{get;set;}
public string plaintext{get;set;}
public string encrptedstring{get;set;}
```

Comment: Why do you want this in the first place? DbContext isn't a database connection and what you show is definitely not an entity. You can't map an unnamed column to an entity

Comment: Client Requirement is to move this SP as API so that it can be used in other applications by using EndPoints and avoiding DB connections.

Comment: You're already using DB connections. EF isn't a database driver, it's an ORM that uses ADO.NET underneath. API endpoints have nothing to do with how you call the database. There are no *entities* involved in what you showed. In EF Core up to 7, you *must* register result types as entities, one way or another

Comment: If all you need is to easily map query results to objects, use [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) : `con.QueryFirst<string>("select student.EncrptString(@plainText,@format)", new {plainText="blah",format="blah"});`. Dapper will map the parameters to properties by name, open the connection, execute the query and map the results. In this case there's only a single string result but it can easily map complex objects. It's the inspiration for the `FromSql...` methods you're trying to use. Dapper *doesn't* require any configuration though

Comment: As for `Client Requirement is to move this SP as API`, why not use protocols made for this job like GraphQL ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much! dapper solved my problem and I got to learn new thing.

Answer (score 0):

`student` should be your database name ? And `EncryptString` is your table name, right ?

I can't believe your stored procedure statement can be excuted. At least you are missing `END` tag.

You should change your stored procedure statement like below

```
create procedure studentencrypt 
@text varchar(100)
@format varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
select * FROM [Your_Db].[dbo].EncrptString WHERE plaintext =@plainText AND format = @Format
END
Go
```

***Unless you have defined a function `EncrptString` method, your statement should not be executed directly. You can copy select student.EncrptString(@plainText,@Format) to execute the test.***

And I found a excellent blog for you, you can check it and learn how to excute the stored procedure in your C# code.

[How to Execute Stored Procedures With EF Core 7](https://code-maze.com/efcore-execute-stored-procedures/)

Comment: Sorry, I missed END statement while writing above.. My SP has END statement and works fine SQL studio.
EncrptString is user define function and dbo is the data base.
SP returns string with no column name.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the issue using DAPPER as recommended by @PanagiotisKanavos.
[Amazing article that explained dapper in depth for new bee like me](https://code-maze.com/using-dapper-with-asp-net-core-web-api/)